Flutter Webview, python
I can’t run the project through flutter! It doesn’t take the location on Android, and the video/camera doesn’t display on iPhone! Help with this, other sites with camera and location support are all working
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter_android/webview_flutter_android.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class FaceIDPage extends StatefulWidget {
const FaceIDPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_FaceIDPageState createState() => _FaceIDPageState();
}

class _FaceIDPageState extends State<FaceIDPage> {
late final WebViewController _controller;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_requestPermissions();
_initializeWebView();
}

Future<void> _requestPermissions() async {
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  await [
    Permission.camera,
    Permission.microphone,
    Permission.location,
  ].request();
} else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  await [
    Permission.camera,
    Permission.location,
    Permission.microphone,
  ].request();
}
}

Future<Position> _getCurrentPosition() async {
bool serviceEnabled;
LocationPermission permission;

serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
if (!serviceEnabled) {
  return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
}

permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
  permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
  }
}

if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
  return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied.');
}

return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
}

void _setGeolocationInWebView(WebViewController controller) async {
try {
  Position position = await _getCurrentPosition();

  await controller.runJavaScript('''
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition = function(success, error) {
      success({coords: {latitude: ${position.latitude}, longitude: ${position.longitude}}});
    };
  ''');
} catch (e) {
  debugPrint('Ошибка при получении координат: $e');
}
}

void _initializeWebView() {
final PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams params = PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();
_controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(
  params,
  onPermissionRequest: (resources) async {
    return resources.grant(); 
  },
)
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setBackgroundColor(Colors.transparent)
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
    NavigationDelegate(
      onPageFinished: (String url) {
        _setGeolocationInWebView(_controller); 
      },
    ),
  )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://pyth.***'));

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final AndroidWebViewController androidController = _controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController;
  AndroidWebViewController.enableDebugging(true);
  androidController.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
  //androidController.setGeolocationEnabled(true); 
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  _controller.runJavaScript('''
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.srcObject = stream;
      video.setAttribute('playsinline', true);
      video.play();
      document.body.appendChild(video);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Ошибка при доступе к камере: ', error);
    });
  ''');
}
}

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('FaceID Верификация'),
  ),
  body: WebViewWidget(controller: _controller),
);
 }
}

The server part runs on python, flask server, app.py includes index.html and then js css, etc.

Chek the permission set up for android and Ios again . https://pub.dev/packages/camera .

For android greater than APi version >33 . Look and implement https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler#faq
